# How to set the output of the Asynchronous Task to the text view of the Main Activity

Tags: java, android

```
public class  CheckLoginCredentialsTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Integer, 
EEmployeeHTTPResponse> {

MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
private ProgressDialog ResponseProgress;
private Activity curActivity;
String employeeId,password;
String IMEI_Number = "";

public void setContextandActivity(Activity activity,String id,String pwd) {
    this.curActivity=activity;
    this.employeeId=id;
    this.password=pwd;
}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
protected EEmployeeHTTPResponse doInBackground(Boolean... param) {
    try {
        HTTPCommunication loginHTTPRequest;
        if (employeeId != null) {
            Log.i("eEmp/CheckLoginTask", "doInBackg");
            loginHTTPRequest = new HTTPCommunication();
            EmployeeInfoDTO loginInfo = new EmployeeInfoDTO();
            Boolean Profile_Required_Status = param[0];
            loginHTTPRequest.setRequestType(EmpConstants.HTTPRequestType.NewUser);

            if (Profile_Required_Status) {  // Profile_Required_Status = Yes
                loginInfo.Profile_Required = EmpConstants.Profile_Required_Yes;
            }
            loginInfo.EMPID = employeeId;
            loginInfo.Password = password;
            return loginHTTPRequest.SendHTTPRequest(loginInfo);
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("eEmp/CheckLogin/Error", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    Log.d("eEmp/ChkLoginTskProg", "onProgress");
}

protected void onPostExecute(EEmployeeHTTPResponse result) {
    String toastStr = "";

    try {
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.HTTPStatusCode == 200) {
                if (result.Data != null) {
                    if (result.Data.ResponseCode == ActionStatus.Codes.UserFound) {
                        EmployeeInfoResponseDTO empDetails = (EmployeeInfoResponseDTO) result.Data.ActionResult;
                        if (empDetails != null) {
                            obj.tvEmpId.setText(empDetails.EmpID);
                            obj.tvType.setText(empDetails.EmpType);
                            obj.tvDept_code.setText(empDetails.DEPT_CODE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("eEmp/CheckLoginTsk", "onPostExecute");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("eEmp/PostExecute", e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

My result that I got from server is in `empDetails` in `onPostExecute` method. In `empDetails` there are 3 fields `EmpID`, `EmpType`, `EmpDept`. Now I need to set these values to the `textviews` in the `MainActivity`.

I created object to the `MainActivity` then I called `obj.textview` But It is not accessing the `textview` from the `MainActivity`.

How can I access the `textview` here. Or if any other methods exists, please tell me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please help me with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set public static all of `textviews` and access it from this class directly using `MainActivity.obj.setText("");`

Comment: I will get by this: MainActivity.tvEmpId.setText(empDetails.DEPT_CODE)

Comment: Thank you very much. Hats off to the stackoverflowers. @Nikhil Solanki Nilu

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `textview` object from `MainActivity` in Constructor of `CheckLoginCredentialsTask` and create object of `textview` in `MainActivity`,Like this

```
TextView tvEmpId,tvType,tvDept_code;


 CheckLoginCredentialsTask (Context context,String id,String pwd,TextView tvEmpId,TextView tvType,TextView tvDept_code)
  {
  this.context=context;
  this.employeeId=id;
  this.password=pwd;
  this.tvEmpId=tvEmpId;
  this.tvType=tvType;
  this.tvDept_code=tvDept_code;
  }
```

and don't create object `MainActivity` like this

```
MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
```

**set text in TextView**

```
 tvEmpId.setText(empDetails.EmpID);
 tvType.setText(empDetails.EmpType);
 tvDept_code.setText(empDetails.DEPT_CODE);
```

**In MainActivity**

```
    TextView  tvEmpId=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmpId);
    TextView  tvType=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvType);
    TextView  tvDept_code=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDept_code);

    CheckLoginCredentialsTask checkLoginCredentialsTask =new CheckLoginCredentialsTask (getApplicationContext(),"id","password",tvEmpId,tvType,tvDept_code);
    checkLoginCredentialsTask.execute();
```

Comment: I did not understand your answer @kamal verma

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that obj you are referring to is not your actual activity, it is only an instance you created yourself, you need to assign it to the passed in value, and the reference you pass must be of type `MainActivity`

Change your class to the following

```
MainActivity obj;

public void setContextandActivity(MainActivity activity,String id,String pwd) {
    this.obj=activity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Try this with on post execute

```
Intent data = new Intent();
 [...]
if (getParent() == null) {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
} else {
    getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

// write this code in your activity where you want to use it .

```
public void finish() {
    if (mParent == null) {
        int resultCode;
        Intent resultData;
        synchronized (this) {
            resultCode = mResultCode;
            resultData = mResultData;
        }
        if (Config.LOGV) Log.v(TAG, "Finishing self: token=" + mToken);
        try {
            if (ActivityManagerNative.getDefault()
                .finishActivity(mToken, resultCode, resultData)) {
                mFinished = true;
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Empty
        }
    } else {
        mParent.finishFromChild(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Access onPostexecute method from your mainactivity as below:

    new CheckLoginCredentialsTask() {
                   @Override
                   protected void onPostExecute(EEmployeeHTTPResponse result) {
                       super.onPostExecute(result);
 try {
               if (result != null) {
                   if (result.HTTPStatusCode == 200) {
                       if (result.Data != null) {
                           if (result.Data.ResponseCode == ActionStatus.Codes.UserFound) {
                               EmployeeInfoResponseDTO empDetails = (EmployeeInfoResponseDTO) result.Data.ActionResult;
                               if (empDetails != null) {
                                   tvEmpId.setText(empDetails.EmpID);
                                   tvType.setText(empDetails.EmpType);
                                   tvDept_code.setText(empDetails.DEPT_CODE);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
               Log.d("eEmp/CheckLoginTsk", "onPostExecute");    } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("eEmp/PostExecute", e.toString());    }

      }.execute();
```